# Шрифты на Mac без Retina Вредны для глаз, Windows шрифты лучше и безопаснее?

Tags: windows, macos, шрифты, ui

Наш глаз не устроен так чтобы читать мыльцо. На ретина все ок. Но когда смотришь на мониторе то шрифты мыльноватые. У меня с глазами есть маленькие нюансы. Короче говоря я не хочу сделать себе хуже. Ретина не подходит от нее глаза болят. К мыло можно привыкнуть но стоит ли? Не вредят ли такие шрифты зрению?

Comment: Для глаз вреден только удар вилкой. Как вы себе представляете нанесение вреда глазу при помощи изображений? И вообще вопрос не по теме SO, да еще и кучу меток наставили неправильных.

Comment: @Anamnian, *ну Javascript тут всё порешает..* :D

Comment: дело не только в шрифтах: освещение, длительность работы и т.д. Работать за монитором вредно по-определению. Нужен правильный режим. (А телевизор, телефон, цвета..., этими вопросами люди занимаются во многих компаниях) Мозг адаптирует восприятие  в этом "опасность", вы привыкаете к любым условиям. Нужно переключаться, гимнастика и т.п.

Comment: @Anamnian как как очень просто - мутный шрифт вреден проконсультируйся у офтальмога